# C# SqlDataReader from Select statement sometimes returns no rows when an Update statement runs Simultaneously

Tags: c#, sql-server, locking, collision, sqldatareader

I have a scenario where I am running multiple SQL queries over a set period of time. Throughout this scenario, there is a chance an Update statement will be running at the same time as the Select statement, affecting the same table. When this happens, my SqlDataReader object runs the Select query and returns no rows. However, immediately retrying the Select query will result in receiving the correct data. The Select statement should realistically never return no data.

Although I can retry the query after the failed read to get the results, I would like to avoid this collision in the first place, or at least have a way to differentiate between actually reading no rows and this collision error occurring. When examining the SqlDataReader object, the only different property that tells me a read failed, is that HasRows is set to false, which is not specific enough for what I am looking for here. Additionally, attempting to read just returns false and does not throw an error potentially saying why the read failed.

So far I have tried putting locks on both the Select and Update queries but I've had no such luck. Ideally the Update statement would have a lock that would **queue, not block**, the Select queries from running until after the transaction completes. I have tried a few different lock variations, but one example I tried was this:

```
update <Tablename> with (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK) set ...
```

This does not stop the collision as I expected, so this is where I am stuck.

Is the best method here to just retry if I know there never should be an empty read, or is there perhaps a better method as I am suggesting using the SQL locks?

Comment: If you are updating a row your select statement should be waiting for the lock to be released. Unless you are using query hints in your update and your read already which would alter this behavior.

Comment: Currently, the only lock statements I have are the ones on my update statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at `Mutex` . You can use it to make sure that only one instance/query is allowed at the same time.

[MSDN - Mutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.mutex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)